# Jenkins - EnvInject plugin - Can not read environment variable from Java

Tags: jenkins

I drive selenium web driver automated scripts in Maven way in Jenkins.
I use EnvInject plugin to set some environment variables in job level
Get 'Inject environment variables to the build process' selected
Input environment variables in Properties Content, like

```
jenkins_productType=offering
jenkins_env=UAT
jenkins_browser=firefox
jenkins_locale=en_US
```

Then start up the build, I got log from console

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
[EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
[EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
Building in workspace C:\CIEnv_Jenkins\jobs\SCWDailyRegression_BasedOnMaven\workspace
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content



jenkins_productType=offering
jenkins_env=UAT
jenkins_browser=firefox
jenkins_locale=en_US

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
```

I expect I can get those environment variables in Selenium web driver scripts by java, such as

```
Boolean localSetting = System.getenv().containsKey("jenkins_locale");
```

I always get localSetting as false, that means no such environment variable was set.
Can anyone help me out? Very appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using this [method](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin#EnvInjectPlugin-Injectvariablesasabuildstep) to set your env ? it seems it exists multiple method and usage for this plugin

Comment: Yes, I did use ''Inject environment variables to the build process", provide Key/Value pair in Properties Content